# Should I use GDP deflator on variable that already is a price index?

Tags: data

I'm using the KLEMS 2009 database to study productivity and wage evolution in Europe. To measure productivity I'm using a variable called VA_P which is described as 'Gross Value Added, price indices, 1995 = 100'.

I've deflated labour compensation with CPI in order to reflect the real purchase power of employees, but I'm wondering if I should also deflate the value added with a GDP deflator, since I'm already working with a price index. I think I'm missing something?

Comment: The answer depends on your structural model. If it includes variables in real terms, then it is wise to deflate nominal variables by the suitable deflator.

Comment: @Bertrand sure, but that's not really my question. I want real variables. The question is if an index that uses fixed 1970 prices is real.

Comment: Yes, is is real, as it depends only upon elementary quantities.    A good reference is Balk B.M., 2008, Price and Quantity Index Numbers, Cambridge University Press